# To what does 'body' refer in this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple piece of code in `jQuery`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#switcher').click(function(event) {
           if ($(event.target).is('.button')) {
            $('body').removeClass();
                if (event.target.id == 'switcher-narrow') {
               $('body').addClass('narrow');
            }
            $('#switcher .button').removeClass('selected');
            $(event.target).addClass('selected');
        }
    });
});
```

for this html code :

```
<body>
    <div id="switcher" >
        <h3>Style Switcher</h3>
        <div class="button selected" id="switcher-default">
        Default
        </div>
        <div class="button" id="switcher-narrow">
        Narrow Column
    </div>
</body>
```

I have a very simple, yet tricky question (at least for me) : what does `body` refer to ?

I imagine that it encapsulates everything under `#switcher` but then my `h3` style would disappear on click.

Comment: open any html file...what is the main content element?  jQuery is targeting that elemnt

Comment: To the `<body>` element in the HTML.

Comment: That would refer to your <body> tag.... isnt it..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It refers to the element `<body>`.

Answer (score 1):

`$('body')` refers to the `<body>`...

you can select by tagName in `jQuery`. Ao `$('div')` refers to all the divs
and `$('body')` refers to all the bodies(only one exist...)

Answer (score 1):

$('body') is the body element.

It's trying to remove any classes that exist on the body tag.